# Problems with functions in Action Script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, events, event-handling, listener

I have three functions to releaase when button clicked. They're almost the same, written down one after the other. My problem is that first function (pasted below) works, but when I click second and third button nothing happens. Code for second and third button is the same, but different variables are used.

```
redStarts.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redBars);

function redBars(event:Event)
{
    red1Starts.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, r1);
    red2Starts.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, r2);
    red3Starts.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, r3);

    function r1(event:Event)
    {
        if (red1Starts.y > 200){red1Starts.y -= 4};
    }

    function r2(event:Event)
    {
        if (red2Starts.y > 20){red2Starts.y -= 4};
    }

    function r3(event:Event)
    {
        if (red3Starts.y > 120){red3Starts.y -= 4};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Avoid using nested functions. It seems like that the variables' values you mentioned are persisted in the closures. Try it this way:

```
redStarts.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redBars);

function redBars(event:Event)
{
  red1Starts.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, r1);
  red2Starts.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, r2);
  red3Starts.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, r3);
}

function r1(event:Event)
{
  if (red1Starts.y > 200){red1Starts.y -= 4};
}

function r2(event:Event)
{
  if (red2Starts.y > 20){red2Starts.y -= 4};
}

function r3(event:Event)
{
  if (red3Starts.y > 120){red3Starts.y -= 4};
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, problem was with adding to stage, some of items was not converted correctly to movieClip and that was the cause of my problem.